# Why does Rails 3 nested route ignore nesting resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, routes

Associations:

```
location  has_many :comments
comment  belongs_to :location
```

For some reason, this GET:

```
/locations/5/comments.json
```

is acting like this GET:

```
/comments.json

Started GET "/locations/5/comments.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-10 21:18:00 -0700
  Processing by CommentsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"location_id"=>"5"}
  Comment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" 
Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Note the SQL query: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments"

The route is set up like this:

```
  resources :locations do
    resources :comments
  end
```

Rake routes confirms the route:

```
location_comments GET    /locations/:location_id/comments(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments"}
```

Here is the index action:

```
 def index
    @comments = Comment.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @comments }
    end
  end
```

Is this the right action? It is consistent with the result, but I am not sure what else should be here. I've never had a problem with nested resources before, so I've never looked into the details.

Comment: I don't seem to find anything unexpected. What's wrong with this ?

Comment: The resulting query should be SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."location_id" = 5.

Comment: No, nesting won't make the query automagical. If it would, how would you get all the comments, without regard to a location. May be something like `@comments = Comment.all.without_nesting`, which imo is less clean than doing it the conventional way.
 In your case, you could easily get the comments of a specific location as suggested by @Patrick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
def index
  @location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
  @comments = @location.comments
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @comments }
  end
end
```

Comment: You can also replace the whole `respond_to` block with:  `respond_with @comments`

Comment: Thanks Patrick, this will work, but at the cost of knocking out the regular index action for comments. Can you confirm that I am wrong in my assumption that the nesting should work automagically to produce a SQL query with a condition like WHERE "comments"."location_id" = 5? and that I have to actually rewrite an action to make this work?

Comment: a slightly ugly conditional restores the regular index action: if params[:location_id]

Comment: I don't think that's ugly at all and should work well.  If your controller method gets much more complicated you can ref actor it into a presenter (another topic all together)